# Why does Ruby run only some tests and not others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, testunit

I'm using this command to run some tests...

```
bundle exec ruby -Itest test/functional/*.rb
```

In my `test/functional` dir I have two files...

```
file_sets_controller_test.rb
user_sessions_controller_test.rb
```

With the above command, the tests in `file_sets_controller_test.rb` all run but the ones in `user_sessions_controller_test.rb` don't run at all -- no errors or other output is reported.

However, I can run that file directly no problem, with this...

```
bundle exec ruby -Itest test/functional/user_sessions_controller_test.rb
```

That works fine.

I know that another option is to use `rake test functionals`, but that is extremely slow compared to running them directly.

---

```
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]

Rails 3.2.12
```

---

Here's a part of my Gemfile...

```
group :development, :test do

  gem 'ansi'
  gem 'turn'

  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'minitest-matchers'

end
```

And here's my `test_helper.rb`...

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

require 'turn/autorun'
Turn.config.ansi = true

require 'minitest/autorun'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  fixtures :all

end
```

Removing the Turn and Minitest gems doesn't change anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: You do know about `rake test:functionals`, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ruby` command takes a ruby file to run as its first argument and makes additional arguments available to the ruby program. The shell is expanding your glob expression into 2 arguments and passing them to `ruby`, so `ruby` is running the first file name in the expansion.

Additional:

I think you can do what you want with something like...

```
bundle exec ruby -Itest -e "Dir.glob('test/functional/*_test.rb').each{|f| require File.expand_path(f)}"
```

Comment: Sure about that? When I run tests (in a old version of Rails) the command always have all files as **one** string, files separated with space within the string.

Comment: Oops that's my mistake, doh! Steve & 244an I owe you a beer. Steve if you edit your answer a bit I can change my downvote to an upvote. (The command works on my setup because I have code intercepting the glob).

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson It's not clear to me what edit you're suggesting. Can you clarify?